# Breaking out of a loop in XSL

Tags: xslt

I have a situation where I need to loop through one or more funds within a policy record, find the one that has the code TVFIR1 and use that record’s interest rate. This is a super simplified version of the XML record:

```
<Policy>
    <PolicyNumber>123456789</PolicyNumber>
    <PolicyOwner>John Doe</PolicyOwner>
    <Fund>
        <FundCode>TVSPM3</FundCode>
        <InterestRate>0</InterestRate>
    </Fund>
    <Fund>
        <FundCode>TVFIR1</FundCode>
        <InterestRate>0.025</InterestRate>
    </Fund>
    <Fund>
        <FundCode>TVMDP5</FundCode>
        <InterestRate>0</InterestRate>
    </Fund>
</Policy>
```

This is what I am aiming to achieve in pseudocode:

```
For each fund
  If the fund code = ‘TVFIR1 Then
    Get its interest rate
    Break out of the loop
  Else
    Interest rate = 0
  End If
```

Next fund record

The logic I would like to use isn’t supported in XSL because you can’t break out of a for-each loop (it's not a procedural language!).

Answer (score 1):

Why loop when you can do so in one expression? I believe this XPATH would work for you:

```
/Policy/Fund[FundCode='TVFIR1']/InterestRate || number(0)
```

That would select the value of the InterestRate whose FundCode is 'TVFIR1' or the number 0 if it does not exist. Just use that as the value of a variable.

Comment: That's not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: I think you were aiming at the XPath 2.0 expression `(/Policy/Fund[FundCode='TVFIR1'][1]/InterestRate, 0)[1]`

Comment: I would always trust @MichaelKay for sure ... I ran that Xpath in Oxygen (2.0) and did not get an error, changing the FundCode to various values and it seemed to work.

Comment: The "||" is introduced in XPath 3.0 as a string concatenation operator, which makes the above exression valid; but it means that when the InterestRate actually exists and is 0.025, then the result of the expression is 0.0250, which works perhaps by accident or perhaps by design.

Comment: I would try Michael kay's xpath in comments if you are using 2.0 and check to be sure you are matching something (is the context correct?)

Comment: You are right about the concatenation of the 0 to the interest rate and this is not what I want. I am trying to use the (/Policy/Fund[FundCode='TVFIR1'][1]/InterestRate, 0)[1] statement but when there is a valid interest rate (say 0.025) then the result is 0.025 0.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you try it this way:

```
<xsl:template match="/Policy">
    <!-- other stuff -->
    <xsl:variable name="fund" select="Fund[FundCode='TVFIR1']" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$fund">
            <xsl:value-of select="$fund/InterestRate"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <!-- more stuff -->
</xsl:template>
```

This is assuming you're using XSLT 1.0.

---

If you are using XSLT 2.0, then you can shorten this to:

```
<xsl:template match="/Policy">
    <!-- other stuff -->
    <xsl:variable name="fund" select="Fund[FundCode='TVFIR1']" />
    <xsl:value-of select="if ($fund) then $fund/InterestRate else 0"/>
    <!-- more stuff -->
</xsl:template>
```

I would advise you to avoid "clever" tricks that might seem cool at first, but will cost you (or your successor) time later when you try to decipher what exactly they do.

As you have yourself indicated, this is a "if then else" problem and should be solved as such - even if the solution may seem a bit verbose.